# How do I use AnimatePresence with AnimatedSharedLayout in framer motion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I have a container which can possible display several child containers based on state. When the state changes (based on a button click), I would like:

1. The current container to fade out
2. The height of the main container to animate to the be the height of its new child container
3. The new child container to fade in

I feel like I'm on the right track with my demo, but the AnimatePresence seems to be ignored as none of the opacity animations are working. I'm hoping someone can please take a look and let me know what I need to adjust?

https://codesandbox.io/s/animating-shared-layouts-with-content-changing-h8hvq?file=/src/App.js

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row" />
      <div className="row" />
    </div>
  );
}

function Contact() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row" />
      <div className="row" />
      <div className="row" />
      <div className="row" />
      <div className="row" />
    </div>
  );
}

const sections = {
  home: "Home",
  contact: "Contact"
};

export default function App() {
  const [activeSection, setActiveSection] = useState(sections.home);

  return (
    <div className="outer-container">
      <AnimateSharedLayout>
        <motion.div layout initial={{ borderRadius: 25 }}>
          <h3>Text on top</h3>

          <AnimatePresence key={activeSection} exitBeforeEnter initial={false}>
            <motion.div
              initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
              animate={{
                opacity: 1,
                transition: { delay: 1.2, duration: 1 }
              }}
              exit={{
                opacity: 0,
                transition: { delay: 0, duration: 1 }
              }}
            >
              <div className="inner-container">
                <div className="content">
                  <div className="avatar" />
                  {activeSection === sections.home && <Home />}
                  {activeSection === sections.contact && <Contact />}
                </div>
              </div>
            </motion.div>
          </AnimatePresence>
        </motion.div>
      </AnimateSharedLayout>

      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() =>
          setActiveSection(
            activeSection === sections.home ? sections.contact : sections.home
          )
        }
      >
        Go to {activeSection === sections.home ? "Contact" : "Home"} section
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am seeing the components fade out and then in though?

Comment: I am also missing it.  The codesandbox looks to do what you are describing.

Comment: Sorry guys. I fixed it within the same sandbox.